# How to sort ActiveRecord Relation results on a custom logic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a table containing a number of location objects(columns are `id`, `latitude` and `longitude`). I select rows from this table based on some query, then for these results, I want to find the distance of each location (using `latitude` and `longitude` of this point) from a custom point. How do I sort it on a manual logic? Here is what I tried:

```
# Location Model

def self.search(params, fields, user, employee_id)
    marker = SearchHelper.change_to_point(params[:marker_distance_sort])

    results = self.select(columns_selected) # The type for results is ActiveRecord_Relation


    # What should I do here for custom sorting?
    results.sort_by { |a, b| a.distance_from_marker(marker) <=> b.distance_from_marker(marker)}

end

def self.distance_from_marker(marker)
    marker.distance(FACTORY.point(self.attributes['longitude'], self.attributes['latitude']))
end
```

Sorry I am really new to ruby on rails and I have tried every resource available on stack overflow answers for custom sorting. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you try `sort` method on `results` variable?

Comment: Yeah tried that too! Didn't work

Comment: (1) The block for `sort_by` takes one argument so you'd `results.sort_by { |a| a.distance_from_marker(marker) }`. (2) If you can express `distance_from_marker` in SQL then you could let the database do the sorting, how you do this depends (at least partly) on what database you're using.

Comment: That works well. But I am getting an array object, but I want ActiveRecord_Relation object, how to change it to acitive_record relation object?